# Angular - Is node-sass supported in the node version 11?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, node-sass

I have this new error which is failing the compilation of the code.
Is it the problem with the node version?

Is node-sass supported in all node versions?

If not how to fix this?

```
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

Comment: You can try this `npm rebuild node-sass --force` or `npm install node-sass`. That will fix node-sass issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npm rebuild node-sass` and see if it fixes your problem (you may have to run with `--force`)

You should run this every time you change your environment (ie: node version).